# How to Save Video Files Created By MediaRecorder to Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-camera, mediarecorder

I'm attempting to replace the photo functionality of the `Mealspotting tutorial` with videos instead as an exercise. Following the tutorial and google's Camera tutorials, I've managed to set up a `MediaRecorder object and a CameraFragment` that starts and stops with button clicks, but I cannot figure out how to save the photo to Parse and then retrieve it.

Do I have to save the video file to the device first? Or can I send the video file directly to Parse like you can do with photos? If so, how?

Right now it seems like I have to call `mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile` and give it a file path, and then somehow retrieve that file to send the file to Parse. Note that all I want to do is to `get the file data in bytes`, just like you're supposed to do with photos.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the data in bytes, you don't need to save it to the device.

```
byte[] data = "Working at Parse is great!".getBytes();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);
file.saveInBackground();
```

After this has saved:

```
ParseObject jobApplication = new ParseObject("JobApplication");
jobApplication.put("applicantName", "Joe Smith");
jobApplication.put("applicantResumeFile", file);
jobApplication.saveInBackground();
```

This is the example from https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#files

As long as you can convert your video to a byte array, you should be able to create a ParseFile and save it to a ParseObject

Comment: I understand, and this is exactly how the vanilla tutorial saves a photo. However my question is not how to save data to a device, but how to obtain the video file so that I can call .getBytes() on it in the first place.